# Выбор из базы данных MySQL из нескольких таблиц

Tags: php, join, база-данных, select, mysql

В базе данных `MySQL` есть таблицы с клиентами, поставщиками и адресами клиентов и поставщиков. И есть таблица всех заказов, в которой хранятся id поставщиков, клиентов и адресов. Как написать запрос, чтобы получить все значения из всех таблиц и вывести все заказы? Т.е. чтобы вместо айдишников из таблицы подставлялись значения из соответствующих таблиц. Допустим таблицы `customer`, `seller`, `address` и `orders`. В `orders` есть `customer_id,seller_id,address_id`. А надо, чтобы при `select * from orders` вместо `id` в вывод подставлять значения этих айдишников - имена, названия, адреса.
p.s. пишу на php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для решения вашей задачи, необходимо использовать [`JOIN`](http://webextends.net/articles/9-mysql/8-mysql-join.html)

Код на [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f76756/1)

UPD 1: По неизвестной причине я не могу больше писать комментарии. 
Проверьте типы данных, что бы не получилось так, что в запросе будут сравниваться например  текстовые адреса(varchar) с id(int) - это может быть одной из причин, почему у вас пропадает половина записей. А лучше скиньте дамп структур таблиц на [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com). Решение где-то рядом в банальной ошибке, надо понять где. Да, по дампу таблиц можно будет поднять их на SQLFiddle и уже смотреть конкретно на запросы.

Comment: Не то. Не выводятся все заказы. Отфильтровывает почему-то. Надо чтобы несколько джоинов не были условием фильтрации, а заменяли айдишники на соответствующие значения.

Comment: Ну, телепаты все в отпуске... 
Показывайте запрос, будем смотреть детальнее.

Comment: > Надо чтобы несколько джоинов не были условием фильтрации, а заменяли айдишники на соответствующие значения.

@Zepp - вы видимо пока плохо понимаете что происходит в запросе. В запросе указано не условие фильтрации, а условие "склеивания" таблиц по id записей

Comment: А в чем разница? Как написать правильный запрос?
$query = "SELECT id,customer_id,seller_id,c_address,s_address,c.name,s.name,a1.address,a2.address FROM orders o JOIN customer c ON o.customer_id=c.id JOIN seller s ON o.seller_id=s.id JOIN address a1 ON o.c_address=a1.id JOIN address a2 ON o.s_address=a2.id";

Comment: @Zepp - У вас два поля имеют одно название в двух разных таблицах, дайте полям псевдонимы.
`c.name,s.name заменить на c.name customer_name, s.name seller_name`

Что у вас вывел этот запрос? каких-то данных не хватает? Возможно для каких-либо ключей у вас не хватает записей в других таблицах, вы допускаете такую ситуацию?

Comment: Да, половины записей не хватает.
Нет, не допускаю. Данные не добавятся, если чего-то будет не хватать, а ключи все берутся из селектов, в оптион которых вставляются значения из БД. Значит других айдишников быть не может.
Добавил псевдонимы, но выводит те же записи. И для адресов тоже псевдонимы, правильно?

Comment: @Zepp - Соответствует ли ваша структура таблиц по *типам* данных:

`orders(
id int,
customer_id int,
seller_id int,
c_address int,
s_address int);`

customer(
id int,
name varchar);

seller(
id int,
name varchar);

address(
id int,
name varchar);`

?

Comment: *оффтоп*: имена таблиц у вас то во множественном числе, то в единственном, вы уж определитесь =)

Comment: Размер инт и варчар тоже должен быть одинаковый? Странно, делаю джоины по одному. Некоторые выводят все записи, некоторые половину не выводят. Похоже где-то у меня орфографическая ошибка. Буду искать. Спасибо за помощь!)